# How to resize Image to button?

Tags: android, image, android-studio

So I have an `ImageButton` but the image is a very big fit for it. I tried `android:scaleType="center"` and it failed because the image centered but it was too small and tried `fitXY` but same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f1e8e8"
    tools:context="com.example.bassam.myapplication123.MainActivity">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:padding="100dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/Work"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        ></ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you share the screenshot that you want to achieve

Comment: put the drawable in the background `android:background="@drawable/Work"`

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/cpn21024h/
@PhanVănLinh

Comment: @DkgMarine also share the image that you want to achieve

Comment: @SecretCoder i was trying something else and forgot to remove it lol

Comment: @DkgMarine what do you mean trying to remove it? lol

Comment: @PhanVănLinh you mean this http://postimg.org/image/y2x5644w1/  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If how I understand your concern is correct, you simply just want to have the image scale to the size of the `ImageButton` itself, simply use

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

The image is adjusted depending on the size of the `ImageButton`. Try it out and let me know if it works. Cheers! :)

Comment: I noticed that you have a `background` element and a `src` element. Is there a reason why you need to separate elements? If you are aiming to cover the ImageButton with an image, why not just set the `background` with the image itself. I tried it on my end where the `background` is set to the image you want.

Comment: No worries. Cheers! :D